# What is the difference between 'tweaking' and 'fine-tuning'?

Tags: differences

When I say  'after some tweaking and fine-tuning', are they different processes, or am I just being redundant?

Comment: I'd say you're *dotting the i's and crossing the t's*. Which metaphorically is a single process, not meaningfully subdividable into two phases.

Comment: Nearly interchangeable  in all uses. Tweaking might include some other meanings or adaptations of the device in question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers While I agree that put together they are one process, I think you can easily separate them into individual processes.  You would be perfectly reasoned to say "after some tweaking." (Alternately, "fine tuning")  Hence, it is redundant, but forgivably so.

Comment: @David: Okay, shall we do the tweaking first, or the fine-tuning? Or maybe we could get two teams on the job(s), doing them *in parallel*, so we can get it done within the project deadline. Maybe a bit of a problem assigning the sub-tasks, but we'll have time to spare for that, since we've potentially saved half of it already! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think I've made my point a little more eloquently below than above.  :-)  (I tweaked and fine-tuned it!)

Answer (score 2):

*Tweaking and fine-tuning* are both substitute terms for *making small adjustments*.

In terms of processes, they are effectively exactly the same because neither is a formal process (at least in the usage you've described).

In using both in the same sentence, you *could* be accused of semantic redundancy.  But, I would say that this usage serves more as an intensifier than a redundancy.  You're giving the sense of a greater level of detail by using both.

As an interesting side note, the literal definition of *tweaking* is twisting or pulling something sharply.  Somehow the usage transformed to mean making fine adjustments, which seems antithetical to the original meaning!

Answer (score 2):

I think that fine tuning implies that you are taking something that is working and making it work a little bit better or at least hoping that it works a little better.

Tweaking could be used in the same way as fine tuning but often tweaking would be used to note making changes to something that is not functioning correctly.

If I was done developing an app and during a demo it crashed I might say, "I might need to tweak this a bit.  Let me get back to you on this in a bit."  If they wanted a mouse hover to last a little longer or something in a different color I might say, "Cool, let me do some fine tuning after the input."

Answer (score 1):

With respect to an instrument, the act of tweaking will be an initial significant adjustment to make it to work; it may not be possible by tweaking to put it in an optimum working level. The control parameter of an instrument needs to be fine-tuned to work at the desired level. This is applicable to all scenarios. I believe it is a sequential process - tweaking and then fine-tuning.

Answer (score 0):

To me, the two denote the same thing: making fine adjustments to something.  There is a slight difference in connotation, however:

*Tweak*, when used in the same sense as *fine-tune*, is more informal or familiar than the latter.  It is a bit geekier, if you like.
[Here](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=tweak+definition&ie=UTF-8&rlz=2T4GGHP_enUS0537US0537&q=tweak+definition&gs_l=hp...0j0i22i30l4.0.0.0.3620...........0.60JxX0R12ZE) is a characterization of both senses of *tweak*.

The main, literal, and original meaning of *tweak* is physical: to twist, jerk, pull, or rotate something (e.g., a knob). 
Figuratively, *tweak* means to fine tune something, whether physical or not (e.g., an estimate).

*Fine tuning* is not necessarily physical or informal.  It is a neutral word used by anyone in any context.

As to whether it generally makes sense to use both in the same sentence: no.  Pick one.